# Detectar numeros decimales

Tags: python-3.x

Hola tengo un problema a la hora de hacer divisiones, lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un programa para solucionar problemas matemáticos básicos con su procedimiento completo, el problema es que quería crear una función que encuentre el máximo común divisor con su debida descomposición en factores primos y la idea era detectar cuales números eran exactos y cuales no y se me ocurrió hacer una comprobación parecida a esto:

```
a=5/5
if type(a)==float:
    print('decimal')
else:
    print('entero")
```

Pero hay un problema, y es que al dividir números sin importar de que tipo sean siempre el resultado aun siendo entero lo devuelve como decimal no se como solucionar eso o si hay una mejor forma de hacerlo.

Comment: Bienvenido Alex Madrid a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: `int(a) == a` es True cuando `a` es entero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La división en Python 3x siempre retorna un `float`. Lo que puedes hacer es verificar si el resultado es un entero mediante [`is_integer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer):

```
a=5/5
if not a.is_integer():
  print('decimal')
else:
  print('entero')
```

Ejemplo:

```
print((1.00001).is_integer())
print((1.0).is_integer())

False
True
```